# Do two classes declarations differing from a friend class make an ODR violation?

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

Consider `a.hpp`

```
class foo{
  int c;
};
```

and `b.hpp`

```
class bar;
class foo{
  friend bar;

  // from here identical to a.hpp
  int c;
};
```

Is it, strictly speaking, an ODR-violation?

Comment: "differing for a class friend" they do not differ by anything, they are identical

Comment: Yes, but in the second class there is a way to access the private data through `bar`, in the first, there is none.

Comment: why not in the first?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: made a copy-paste error, the first declaration has no friends, edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. ODR is clear, from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) (emphasis mine):

> There can be more than one definition in a program of each of the following: class type, [...], as long as all of the following is true:
>
> - [... some other points...]
> - each definition consists of **the same sequence of tokens** [...]
> - [...]

The first token in class `foo` definition in `b.hpp` the "`friend`" token differs from "`int`" token inside class `foo` definition in `a.hpp` - just this is enough. Note how restrictive that point is - it talks about *tokens*, not even about meaning of these tokens (but note there are also other points with further restrictions). If these two header files are meant to be used in two translation units that are going to be linked together, ODR is violated.

Comment: Thank you, I looked at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class, but as there only list of access specifiers, member object and member function declarations and definitions where listed, so from this definition it seemed to me that the declaration where equivalent, as `friend bar;` does not seem to be part of the declaration.

Comment: *"not even about meaning of these tokens."* That is in another point, symbol should also refer to same entity (in particular previous declaration of overload might break ODR).

Comment: @fekir cppreference is amazing and great but it's not an actual standard - thankfully it has an easy to understand version. A `friend bar;` is one of [member-declarations](https://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem.general-2) that are inside [member-specification](https://eel.is/c++draft/class#nt:member-specification) inside a [class-specifier](https://eel.is/c++draft/class#pre-1).